# Lib is unable to load web worker script after importing it from react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, worker

I have a library that uses a web worker like so: `new Worker(new URL(process.env.WORKER_URL as string, import.meta.url), { type: "module"})`.

This works fine on my development server but when I link it to my react project via `npm link`, the worker script doesn't get fetched correctly. I know this because

1. I get an error saying `Loading Worker from “http://localhost:3000/static/js/277.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`
2. I am unable to see the file in my dev tools.

I am using typescript, webpack, and react.